# С помощью рефлексии в java получить поле или метод

Tags: java

Все кажется просто:

```
Class c = user.getClass();
Field field = c.getField("id");
```

Но все крешется с  ошибкой NoSuchFieldException
Зато код:

```
Class c = user.getClass();
Field field = c.getDeclaredField("id");
```

Все  работает. Так в чем разница? Во всех примерах используется 1 вариант но он не работает :(

Comment: приведите пример класса для которого первый вариант не работает. [Ну и вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966629/what-is-the-difference-between-getfields-and-getdeclaredfields-in-java-reflectio)

Comment: Метод `getField()` возвращает только открытые члены данных класса... видимо `id` приватный или протектед

Comment: Да,  и в самом деле только публичные... глупый вопрос наверно был...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

О, это одна из хитростей Java, `getField` - возвращает только публичные или унаследованные от суперклассов поля, а `getDeclaredField` - возвращает все поля класса... но не унаследованные от суперклассов поля (скажем вполне публичное поле, но доставшийся от суперкласса этот метод просто не увидит), так что если нужно вернуть действительно **все** нужно писать что-то вроде:

```
Field field;
try { 
   field = c.getField("id");
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    field = c.getDeclaredField("id");
}
```